# streaming audio from iphone to server (HTTP streaming )

Tags: iphone, streaming, asihttprequest

I use this code below to upload an audio file to server from disk.
I want to upload the file as a stream directly from iphone mic to server ..
using speakHere example we can capture the audio packets on the fly as they been recorded .

### I tried many times and searched on it with no clue !!

```
NSString *fullPathToFile = [recordedAudioFilesDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%i.wav",1,2 ]];


//..REMARK ,,change ayah froma nd ayah to and SurahID

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: WEB_SERVICE_ADDRESS] ];




requestGlob = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]  ;
requestGlob.tag=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1000%i",1] intValue];
requestGlob.delegate=self;


[requestGlob setTimeOutSeconds:50];
[requestGlob setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];
[requestGlob setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
[requestGlob setShouldStreamPostDataFromDisk:NO];
[requestGlob setUseCookiePersistence:NO];
[requestGlob setUseSessionPersistence:NO];
[requestGlob setUseKeychainPersistence:NO];
[requestGlob setUploadProgressDelegate:self];



NSString *userName =@"f@ola.com";

NSLog(@"username is %@",userName);
//hashed md5 password//e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
NSString *passowrd =@"q";
//NSLog(@"password is %@",passowrd);
 NSData *authData1 = [userName dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
//encoded username

NSString *encodedUsername = [NSString stringWithString: [authData1 base64Encoding]];
//username + : + password

NSString *combined =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",  encodedUsername,passowrd ];
//encoded combined

NSString *encodedEveryThing= [NSString stringWithString:[[combined dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64Encoding]];
//the most important line since username and password are not arguments and its embedded in the header of the html

[requestGlob addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",encodedEveryThing]];




 [requestGlob appendPostDataFromFile:fullPathToFile];

[requestGlob startAsynchronous];
```

any ideas ?! thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well After digging and suffering  .. I found a simple way to do that ..

and I uploaded my code to  [github-MOUploadAudioStreamer](https://github.com/MoathOthman/MOAudioUploadStreamer)

Hope it helps somebody after all ..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use ASIHTTPRequest library. It can upload files directly from the phone instead of loading the file into memory first.

For more detail you can try Rosywriter provided by apple itself.From this you would get detailed idea.

Have a look at [Rosywriter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html) here.

Enjoy Programming !

Comment: am using ASI  already .. Any sample code or editing to my code would be appreciated ..